# IONIC Cordova retrieve InAppBrowser URL

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I am creating an Ionic 3 application, I need to get the URL from the frame generated from inAppBrowser.

The frame is created here :

```
var browser = this.inAppBrowser.create("http://apache.org", "_blank", "location=no,clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes");
browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(function(event) {
  browser.show();
  console.log(event.url);
});
```

I use the apache website for testing purposes but the url is meant to change as the user goes through the webpage, that is why I'm trying to retrieve it through an event.

My problem is that the "event.url" property keeps returning "null".

**Version : IONIC 3.2.0 ; Cordova 8.0.0**

Many thanks for whoever will help me!

FIX : I found the solution, the desktop browser is always returning null, I tried on a android simulator and it works !

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: How about `console.log(event)`? Can you share the result of this?

Comment: Sure here it is : https://ibb.co/k7ta28

Comment: Nothing I can see via the link :(

Comment: Oh that's unfortunate

Comment: try on `loadstart` event

Comment: I'll try, thanks you for your help

Comment: This is not showing any console.log on my navigator. I don't think that loadstart is working

Comment: do you check these things on a device?

Comment: also remove `browser.show();` inside `subscribe` function